# How do we know there are only 16 Dirac bilinears?

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

We know there are 5 types of bilinears in 4 dimensions, all of them add up to contribute with 16 independent DoF (degrees of freedom). Namely, these bilinears are known as: scalar (1DoF), pseudoscalar(1DoF), vector(4DoF), pseudovector(4DoF) and tensor (6DoF).

How do we know there are only 16 independent DoF in 4 dimensions? And how do we know these are the only scalars (in the sense of 1x1 matrices) that can be built up from spinors?

Is this somehow connected to "invariant theory" and, let's say, the "primitive invariants" of some group, let's say Spin(1,3)?

Comment: What's wrong with $4^2=16$?  They are *bi*-linears.

Comment: I don't get it. Where does this n^2 comes from and what does it stand for?. Does this mean that for n=5 we would have 25 bilinears?. If so, how could you achieve them? ( scalar (1) + pseudoscalar (1) + vector (5) + pseudovector (5) + antisymmetric rank 2 tensor in 5d (10) add up to 22, not 25).

Comment: $n=4$ since you have 4 of them?

Comment: Do you know Pauli's statement about the completeness and orthogonality of this set of matrices?  W. Pauli, “U ̈ber die Formulierung der Naturgesetze mit fu ̈nf homogenen Ko- ordinaten, Teil II: Die Diracschen Gleichungen fu ̈r die Materiewellen,” Ann. der Phys. (5) 18, 337–354 (1933); “Contributions math ́ematiques `a la th ́eorie des matrices de Dirac,” Ann. Inst. Henri Poincar ́e 6, 109–136 (1936).

Comment: ...neatly summarized in JJ Sakurai's Advanced QM, Appendix C. Any 4x4 matrix can be expanded in this basis, ie as a linear combination of these 16 matrices.

Comment: I'll check it later Cosmas, but sounds promising. :)

Comment: This complete basis serves to produce [Fierz transposition identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fierz_identity), analogous to those for Pauli matrices.

Comment: Ummmm, well, I hate to admit this but I seem to have lost mine, so we are down to only 15 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any $n\times n$ complex matrix will have $2n^2$ independent elements for real and imaginary parts. Gamma matrices must satisfy $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$. If we are considering $n$ dimensional $\gamma$ matrices, this yields $2n^2$ equations of $4n^2$ elements of $\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu$. So this characteristic property reduces half of the DoFs overall. Therefore, we are left with $2n^2\to n^2$ DoFs. Thus, 4-dimensional $\gamma$ matrices can have $4^2=16$ independent matrices.

One thing to remember- **dim$(\gamma^\mu)=n$ has to be even integer always**. Dirac wrote first $i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=H\psi=\alpha_i.p_ic\psi+\beta mc^2\psi$ and $\alpha_i,\beta$ matrices are to be traceless matrices with eigenvalue $\pm1$ that makes them **even-dimensional**. So you can't have any 5-dimensional spinor. Later we identify them as $\alpha_i=\gamma^0 \gamma^i,\beta=\gamma^0$. For reference, check section 1.3 from "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" by Bjorken-Drell.

Answer (score 4):

A bilinear, by definition, is an expression of the form $\bar{\psi}_i A_{ij} \psi_j$, with $A_{ij}$ some matrix. For example, the scalar has $A_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, while the four vector bilinears are when $A$ is equal to one of the gamma matrices. And since $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix, the (complex) vector space of all such matrices has dimension $4\times 4 = 16$, so there are 16 independent bilinears.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Can you check the comment I made up there about the n=5 case? What would happen there? And why don't we consider things like $\bar{\psi}_{i_1} \bar{\psi}_{i_k} A_{i_1 i_2 ... i_{2k}} \psi_{i_{k+1}}...\psi_{i_{2k}}$ for k>1 ?

Comment: @JuanC97 Why do you think there is an $n=5$ case? I am not aware of spinors with 5 components, at least not in 4 dimensions.

Comment: Mathematically I think it wouldn't be so crazy to study the rep theory of SO(1,n-1) for n$\neq$4 still with $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$. I just like to ask myself about these things. What if we would have to generalize the action for the $\psi$ field? Did we already considered all the possibilities just by using terms of the form $\bar{\psi_i}A_{ij}\psi_j$? Do we know how to construct these bilinears if n$\neq$4? - those things would be nice to know.

Comment: @JuanC97 It seems like what you want to understand is [higher-dimensional gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices). My understanding is that you can use them to construct a complete set of spinor bilinears in any dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Another additional situation to the topic that there are no spinors of 5 or more components is that there will be
problem with gamma 5 that is required for the construction of bilinear forms defined on spinors (see Fierz identities etc ) and gamma 5 is only constructed for n=4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/382551)